# Как обратить внимание свёрточной нейронной сети на определенные участки изображения?

Tags: python, изображения, keras

Есть 2 класс изображений: **люди сфотографированы вживую** и сфотографирована **картинка, которая была на экране монитора**, и на ней уже люди.
На снимках экранов есть особенность: **белые точки** экрана (грязь и так далее).
Эти дефекты изображения размером 5х5 пикселей (посчитал в паинте).
Все изображения размером 500х500 пикселей.
Вопрос: как на фреймворке Keras вручную подобрать архитектуру нейронной сети, чтобы она замечала именно эти точки? Лучше ли будет использовать черно-белые изображения? Можно ли это как-то не практически исследовать, а просчитать заранее?

Что должно примерно получиться:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(500, 500, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно заметить, что градиент по яркости вблизи точек будет отличаться от градиентов по остальным участкам фотографии. Основное решение, которое приходит мне в голову - двигаться в сторону выделения участков со скачущим градиентом по яркости и насыщенности, но выводы такого рода необходимо делать, наблюдая выборку.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).